# Data received in child as props is empty

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I'm making call to json from parent and sending the resulted data to child as props. 
But in child data is coming as zero.

**parent.vue**

```
<template>
  <subscriberGraph :propSubData="subData" /> // child component
</template>
<script>
data() {
    return {
      subData: [] // subData declaration
    };
},
methods: {
    async getSubscribers() {
      this.subData = await d3.json("./data/subscribers.json"); // calling json
      console.log("1: ", this.subData); // variable is declared in this file and data is getting displayed here, 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getSubscribers();
  }
 </script>
```

Below is child component.

**subscriberGraph.vue**

```
<script>    
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log("2: ", this.propSubData); // data length: 0 
  }
 props: ["propSubData"]
</script>
```

EDIT: subData is already declared, that's what i've mentioned in the comment beside console.log("1"...). anyway updating the code above pls check.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Does the child component data is same always or changed when data received?

Comment: @palash no errors in browser console.
for now, take it as data won't change. first of all i'm not getting, initial data at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialise the `subData` in the `data` section to use it. Since it will take time to get response from the request, you can use `v-if` condition while the child component is calling. This will prevent rendering the child component before the response is set.

```
<template>
  <subscriberGraph :propSubData="subData" v-if="subData && subData.length>0" /> // child component
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data:()=>{
    return {
      subData:null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async getSubscribers() {
      this.subData = await d3.json("./data/subscribers.json"); // calling json
      console.log("1: ", this.subData); // variable is declared in this file and data is getting displayed here, 
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getSubscribers();
  }
}
```

Comment: I can keep v-if, but that's not the issue, I'm bothered here. I want data to be received in child component. ie in subscriberGraph. also, I have initialized th 'subData' in data() already, pls check updated code in the post.

Comment: If the data is receiving in `subData`, then there won't be any issue in sending it to the child component. Is the data is still not receiving?

Comment: yes, data received in parent, but child is showing empty. in console, first child console is coming , then parent console with data is getting displayed. may be since this is async call in parent, it's getting delayed.

Comment: Since the `v-if` is added, the child component will render only when the data in parent is data even there is delay of response.

Answer (score 0):

adding a watch{} solved the issue.
**subscriberGraph.vue**

```
 <script>    
     export default {
      methods: {
        drawBarGraph(data) {
          console.log("3: ", data); // working now !!
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.drawBarGraph(this.propSubData);
      },
      props: ["propSubData"],
      watch: {
        propSubData: function(newData) {
          this.drawBarGraph(newData);
        }
      }
    </script>
```

you need to watch changes, initially you won't get data because child comp has not yet received data when mounted. Later, when data is received, watch{} observes and updates data, hence data is now available in drawBarGraph().